# 2d array relative to direction on grid

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, grid-layout, directions

I'm working on a program that hides a number in a grid (2d array, 10 columns and 10 rows labeled with array filled with a character such as a . or -) and prints the grid to screen.

a num for row and column are random generated and saved to array as an 'X', only shown when found

The user enters the row and column....then displays that user's guess on the grid to the screen as a character. after that, choose which direction to move...and give hints on where the randomized location for that item is hidden in the array within ten tries total or less(user cannot go to previous guess played during the program).

for example:

```
while (guess <9 || found == false){
cout << "Enter your next move....n, e, s, w, ne, nw, se, sw";   
cin >> d;   
    if (d == 'E' || d == 'e')
        {
        col++;
        guess++;
        array[col][row] = guess;
        cout << "moved east";
        }
    else if (d == 'W' || d == 'w')
        {
        col--;
        guess++;
        array[col][row] = guess;
        cout << "west...";
        }
        ....etc
        else {
        guess++;
        cout << "not valid move. turn is incremented";
        }
```

then after the entire while loop on all those, i display the array again but I can't get the moves to show up other than the first step(need it to do 1, 2, 3...10 or until found=true to display 'X') and am not sure how to give the hint on where the item is hidden based on guess direction. if the item is north above where the user guessed their first starting place(column and row), it should display hint based on that location. How could I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Must be: `while(guess < 9`**&&**`!found`), either condition not met *shall* leave to exiting, so you only stay in the loop if *both* are met... Side note: It is better code *style* not to compare booleans, just use `if(condition)` or `if(!condition)` as in the fixed loop condition.
2. Be aware that you should check your board's borders:

   ```
   if(col > 0)
   {
       --col;
       ++guess;
   ```

   Analogously for the other directions...
3. You need to check, if the field intended to visit already has been visited. Assuming the fields unvisited carry value `0`, you can add the following condition to the border check:

   ```
   if(col > 0 && array[col - 1][row] != 0)
   ```

   Again, other directions analogously.
4. For the hints, calculate the distances of the coordinates between target and current position; if negative, add `'n'` or `'w'` to your hint for vertical or horizontal direction respectively, if positive, `'s'` or `'e'`, otherwise, no hint for the respective direction (easiest variant, prefers diagonal directions first).

Side note `array[col][row]`: Typically, you name the indices of the array the other way round: `array[row][col]`; if iterating, you use outer loop for rows, inner loop for cols (to profit from data locality):

```
for(r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    for(c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
        std::cout << getCharFor(array[r][c]);
```

North and south, with code above, still are associated with vertical, east and west with horizontal direction...

**Edit** in response to your comment:

1. You do not need to check the border you are moving away from...

   ```
   if(d == "e")
   {
       if(/*col > 0 &&*/ col <= 10)
       //^^^^^^^^^ obsolete... 
   }
   ```
2. If your array has a size of `NxN`, then the maximum index you can access is `N - 1`, so you only can go east if you are currently maximally at position `N - 2` (`if(col < N-1)`)
3. If you go diagonally, you have to check both horizontal and vertical direction:

   ```
   if(d == "sw")
   {
       if(row < N - 1 && col > 0) 
   }
   ```
4. If you have determined that you do not exit the board with the designated move, then you can access the field in the designated direction:

   ```
   if(d == "sw")
   {
       if(array[row + 1][col - 1] != 0)
           // visited already; assuming you have initialized the array with 0...
   }
   ```

Side note: For the hints, there is yet an unconsidered problem left: What, if the user does not follow them, and due to this, the program gives a hint to a field that already has been visited???

Comment: while (tries<10 && !found){
cout << "Enter your next move....n, e, s, w, ne, nw, se, sw";   
cin >> d;   
    if (d == 'E' || d == 'e')
        {
 If (row >0 && row <=10){
        row++;
        tries++;
        array[row][col] = guess;}
        if (row > 10){
 cout << "not valid.lost a turn, pick another one";
 tries++;}
 cout << "moved east";
        }
...... updated part. how can i get it to correctly do the bounds check and still show up correctly? if i go east when im on 10, it disappears and move wont show up on any other tries

Comment: I did get the direction hints to work and everything else, except for correction on bounds check and if a place has been visited. the array is filled with placeholders to display such as dots and then when visited will hold a different character such as an x